# Why doesn't my modal transition after appearing?

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs3, inertiajs

i am using inertiajs(vue 3 laravel) the modal component.

the modal appear but the transition does not work.

```
    <teleport to="body">
        <transition leave-active-class="duration-200">
            <div
                v-show="show"
                class="fixed inset-0 overflow-y-auto z-50"
                scroll-region
            >
                <div
                    v-show="show"
                    class="fixed inset-0 transform transition-all"
                    @click="close"
                >
                    <div class="absolute inset-0 bg-black opacity-75" />
                </div>

                <transition
                    enter-active-class="ease-out duration-300"
                    enter-from-class="opacity-0"
                    enter-to-class="opacity-100"
                    leave-active-class="ease-in duration-200"
                    leave-from-class="opacity-100"
                    leave-to-class="opacity-0"
                >
                    <div
                        v-show="show"
                        style="max-width: 800px"
                        class="text-white bg-dark-btn px-6 py-4 rounded-t-2xl overflow-hidden shadow-xl transform transition-all fixed bottom-0 w-full mx-auto right-0 left-0"
                    >
                        <slot v-if="show" />
                    </div>
                </transition>
            </div>
        </transition>
    </teleport>
```

And finally i would like to have a transition like which leaves the bottom like.

I changed the place of the transition tag everywhere.